# Can I flush data implicitly?

Tags: c++, logging, flush, ostream

Is there a way to implicitly flush data to an output stream?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#define log logstream 

int main()
{
  ofstream logstream("test.log");

  log << "Test1" << 123 << endl;     // explicitly flushed
  log << "Test2" << 123;             // ?

  // Test2 not written, yet...

  cout << "Check log file..." << endl;
  int tmp;
  cin >> tmp;
}
```

I would like to be able to log without specifying the `<< endl` manipulator every time.

Comment: Use `<< flush` instead?

Comment: It's pretty standard across most languages that output streams are flushed on a `newline` or stream close. C++ is no different.  Many logging classes implement a timer under the covers, and force a flush when the timer expires.

Comment: @EdHeal: that is *explicit* not *implicit*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`std::unitbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/unitbuf).

```
log << std::unitbuf;
```

And then flush would be done at each insertion.

Comment: So for the log stream I have to specify `log << std::unitbuf;` once, and then everything will be flushed straight away? And the other streams will be unaffected?

Comment: _"flush would be done at each insertion"_ That sounds incredibly inefficient :/

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Yes, but it can be good for logging, when you typically do not buffer.

Comment: @Pietro: That only applies to the stream `log`.

Comment: @Jarod42: It applies to any output stream, e.g.: `std::cout << std::unitbuf;`

Comment: @Pietro: I mean that `log << std::unitbuf;` doesn't modify `std::cout` behavior, ,and indeed, you may also use `std::cout << std::unitbuf;` to affect `std::cout`.